# iTunes Connect - App version detail - No In App Purchase selection

Tags: in-app-purchase, itunes, app-store-connect

I don't know whats going wrong there...

Yesterday i added some new IAP to my project. 
There was a section in the **app version details page**, where i can add my already created IAPs.
Suddenly this section disappears. After i recognized that i made a developer rejection
(because i know in this state i can edit the IAPs). But also in the state developer rejected the IAP-selection view doesn't appear.

I tryed to solve that issue for hours but without success.

Does anybody has an idea? Or does anybody has the same problem?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by deleting all IAPs from "Manage In-App-Purchases" section. After that i created everything from scratch

Answer (score 1):

You wrote "Suddenly this section disappears. After i recognized that i made a developer rejection" - it may not have been 'suddenly' - it may have been after you tapped 'ready to submit binary'.  Are you sure you didn't tap 'ready to submit binary' again?  The selection list appears after you add a screen shot to the IAP and it disappears when you tap 'ready to submit'.  But it should reappear after the binary is 'developer rejected'.